# Weird phpMyAdmin error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Okay i'm having a serious issue with a website. First of all, the most immediate issue is an error i'm receiving when trying to import a database, i get the below error;

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w' at line 1`

The issue appears to be happening at the table it hits upon being imported as only 1/4 of the database actually imports. Now, is this error directly related to phpMyAdmin itself or the contents of the tables?

Comment: That HTML you posted is not descriptive, please post the error message, not the error page

Comment: This is not an error, it's just a html and javascript code ;)

Comment: Is the "error" that your browser is rendering this as text and not HTML?

Comment: It has been a long day, copied and pasted the wrong snippet. Just updated with the error message.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to import an html document in the database. You can't, the import function is for sql or perhaps other formats like csv.

Comment: The import is a direct export from another database

Comment: Ok, jeroen you were right there was for some odd reason HTML at the bottom of the .sql file, however the import process still ends abruptly with no error message (only 1/4 of the tables still being uploaded).

Comment: Can you try to break your export into smaller parts? If that doesn't help, try to export database without phpMyAdmin because it looks like that problem is export from phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score -1):

Check your import file. It probably has some text field that contains that and is not properly escaped.